# Elasticsearch match and boosting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic mapping like:

```
{
  first_name: {
    type: 'text'
  },
  last_name: {
    type: 'text'
  }
}
```

And I have 2 documents. One with first name as `Amit`, and last name `Hello` and the other with first name `Hello` and last name `Amit`.

I've given a boost of 2 to first name and boost of 1 to last name. However, when I search for the keyword: `Amit`, I am seeing the doc with last name `Amit` at the top. The results are as expected when the keyword is `Hello`.

The only difference I am seeing in explain shows something called `docFreq` of the second record to be `2` and `1` for the first.

I am not sure why the second document is getting a higher score. Any help is welcome!

This is the query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "term": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            }, {
                "terms": {
                    "roles": ["influencer"]
                }
            }],
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "first_name": {
                        "query": "Amit",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "last_name": {
                        "query": "Amit",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            }],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}


{
    "_index": "development-users",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "10",
    "matched": true,
    "explanation": {
        "value": 175.57181,
        "description": "sum of:",
        "details": [
            {
                "value": 175.57181,
                "description": "sum of:",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": 43.892952,
                        "description": "weight(last_name:gur in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 43.892952,
                                "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 30,
                                        "description": "boost",
                                        "details": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.2809339,
                                        "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 2,
                                                "description": "docFreq",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 8,
                                                "description": "docCount",
                                                "details": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.1422123,
                                        "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 1,
                                                "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 1.2,
                                                "description": "parameter k1",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 0.75,
                                                "description": "parameter b",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 5.75,
                                                "description": "avgFieldLength",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 4,
                                                "description": "fieldLength",
                                                "details": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 43.892952,
                        "description": "weight(last_name:gurj in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 43.892952,
                                "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 30,
                                        "description": "boost",
                                        "details": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.2809339,
                                        "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 2,
                                                "description": "docFreq",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 8,
                                                "description": "docCount",
                                                "details": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.1422123,
                                        "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 1,
                                                "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 1.2,
                                                "description": "parameter k1",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 0.75,
                                                "description": "parameter b",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 5.75,
                                                "description": "avgFieldLength",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 4,
                                                "description": "fieldLength",
                                                "details": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 43.892952,
                        "description": "weight(last_name:gurjo in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 43.892952,
                                "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 30,
                                        "description": "boost",
                                        "details": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.2809339,
                                        "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 2,
                                                "description": "docFreq",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 8,
                                                "description": "docCount",
                                                "details": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.1422123,
                                        "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 1,
                                                "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 1.2,
                                                "description": "parameter k1",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 0.75,
                                                "description": "parameter b",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 5.75,
                                                "description": "avgFieldLength",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 4,
                                                "description": "fieldLength",
                                                "details": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 43.892952,
                        "description": "weight(last_name:gurjot in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 43.892952,
                                "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 30,
                                        "description": "boost",
                                        "details": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.2809339,
                                        "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 2,
                                                "description": "docFreq",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 8,
                                                "description": "docCount",
                                                "details": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": 1.1422123,
                                        "description": "tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:",
                                        "details": [
                                            {
                                                "value": 1,
                                                "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 1.2,
                                                "description": "parameter k1",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 0.75,
                                                "description": "parameter b",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 5.75,
                                                "description": "avgFieldLength",
                                                "details": []
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "value": 4,
                                                "description": "fieldLength",
                                                "details": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "value": 0,
                "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": 0,
                        "description": "# clause",
                        "details": []
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 0,
                        "description": "weight(enabled:T in 1) [], result of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 0,
                                "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 1,
                                        "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                        "details": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "value": 0,
                "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "value": 0,
                        "description": "# clause",
                        "details": []
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 0,
                        "description": "weight(roles:influencer in 1) [], result of:",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "value": 0,
                                "description": "score(doc=1,freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 1,
                                        "description": "termFreq=1.0",
                                        "details": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The number of documents at this point were only 10.

Comment: So, which is your question?

Comment: @Lupanoide good point. Updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Which query have you used to retrieve the docFreq? How many docs there are in your index?

Comment: Used the explain to find how the scoring was done. Added the queries and response to the question. Search was done for the name "gurjot" in the explain.

Comment: ah ,ok . I never used the explain API, I through you were using the termVector API. However the docFreq in your case is needed to evaluate the IDF measure that is needed to the retrieval algorithm - doc here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#idf . The DocFreq shows the number of documents that contain the term, not the number of matched  docs

Comment: @Lupanoide but why is the docFreq `1` for the first doc then? Essentially both docs contain(and even match the term). And following from it, why is the score different?

Answer (score 0):

Your query has retrieved only a doc, `"_id": "10"`, the second stack inherits at the second clause of your query. The first value argument, `"value": 175.57181`, is the sum of the values of all the clauses, I don't know where you have read `docFreq 1` - in which stack - but it inherits the frequence of certain word - could be also `true` in `enabled` field! - in all your indexed docs